# how to maintain 3 column layout when font size changes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a website with a section with 3 columns, it's responsive and the columns switch from horizontal layout on desktop to being stacked vertically for mobile. This is fine but I have a problem where the columns become different heights from each other if the user changes the font size in their browser. Is there a way to force the column heights to remain even?

Here is the site:
http://www.1wevents.com/
It's the about us section.  It's really, really annoying me. I guess I can add media queries to switch to vertical stacking earlier before the screen gets as small as mobile but is there a way to switch based on the font size in the browser?

Many thanks,

Tony

Comment: You should include the relevant code (or a jsfiddle to it) in your question, instead of a link to a website.

Comment: The columns are different heights for me and I'm on a cinema display. The nature of floats is that if each column is not exactly the same then it looks weird. Generally people who don't care about IE or like work arounds, they will use flexbox. I use display-table on the parent, display table-cell on the children, no floats and I use percentages to size at the min-width and stacked (no floats or display settings) for small viewports.